# Update kernel on fedora without updating whole system

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, linux-kernel

I want to update the (Only Kernel) of my fedora 33 , How do I upgrade it without upgrading whole system, can I do `sudo dnf update kernel*` is it safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you quote the last part, it’s safe:

```
sudo dnf update 'kernel*'
```

You need the quotes to avoid issues if the current directory contains files matching the `kernel*` glob, or if your shell settings cause unmatched globs to be removed from arguments.

This will update only the kernel (typically installing the latest set of packages and removing the oldest set). If the transaction is incomplete, *i.e.* the kernel update would require other packages to be updated, those will either be pulled in too or `dnf` will stop and tell you what’s wrong.

As mentioned by [Artem S. Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/260833/artem-s-tashkinov), it’s a good idea to keep your firmware packages up-to-date as well, so

```
sudo dnf update 'kernel*' '*firmware*'
```

would be better still.